# Only allow number in the thousands before decimal place and 4 decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a RegExp to allow this format : `5555.5555`, and any other number should be parsed out/replaced with an empty string (or something).

I've tried a few different things, namely:

`/((^[\d]{5,})|([\d]{1,4}\.?))/g` - try to get everything that is not accepted and everything within 4 digits of an optional decimal so I can use the match in the `.replace` method.

The ultimate goal is to take an input of `55555555.5555555` and spit back out `5555.5555`. I'm struggling with the fact that it matches a `5.` but doesn't give back the entire `5555.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
let str= "55555555.5555555";
let r= str.match(/\d{4}\.\d{4}/);

console.log(r[0]);
```

Comment: That worked, I was stuck on using `.replace()` (and am still curious as to how to accomplish it with replace) but thank you! Will accept when timer is up